# Installing Microsoft VX1000 webcam

Tags: drivers, webcam

I found a tutorial with people saying it works; here are the instructions I followed.

I opened a shell as root on my system and launched the following:

```
wget http://linuxtv.org/hg/v4l-dvb/archive/tip.tar.gz
tar zxvf tip.tar.gz
cd v4l... (whatever the newly created directory name is)
make all
sudo make install
```

Then I edited `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom` and added `blacklist sn9c102`.

After reboot, I launched `sudo gstreamer-properties`.

However when I type `tar zxvf tip.tar.gz` it displays:

```
tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Why? How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give a link to the tutorial you followed ?

Comment: Sorry, but are you sure you typed that tar command correctly? The error message stated that you mistyped something since even "x" was not given (eXtract) however you wrote you typed "zxvf" so there is the "x" there ...

Answer (score 5):

You should not have a need for installing the drivers manually. Even on my Kubuntu 10.04 Lucid, the MS Lifecam VX-1000 webcam is automatically recognized.

After connecting the USB device the next messages show up in the kernel log:

```
usb 3-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
usb 3-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Linux video capture interface: v2.00
gspca: main v2.7.0 registered
gspca: probing 045e:00f7
sonixj: Sonix chip id: 11
gspca: probe ok
gspca: probing 045e:00f7
gspca: probing 045e:00f7
usbcore: registered new interface driver sonixj
sonixj: registered
usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

Relevant descriptions for the modules:

- `gspca_main`: GSPCA USB Camera Driver
- `gspca_sonixj`: GSPCA/SONIX JPEG USB Camera Driver

I used the *Open capture device* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) with *Video for Linux 2* in the VLC player to verify that the camera works.

Answer (score 1):

Change `tar zxvf tip.tar.gz` command to `tar -zxvf tip.tar.gz`

-

The tar command

```
Usage: tar [OPTION]… [FILE]…

Let us check the option used in this example

-c, –create               create a new archive
-z, –gzip, –ungzip        filter the archive through gzip
-v, –verbose              verbosely list files processed
-f, –file=ARCHIVE         use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```