# How to get my hardware working for Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: printing, hardware, skype, webcam, microphone

I have a webcam, mic, and printer I want to get working (if possible) on Kubuntu 14.04.

The webcam is the highest priority for what I want to get working. Currently, it works in cheese, but isn't working at all in Skype (the option for a video call isn't even there).

I'm using a  Microsoft LifeCam VX-1000.

A Snowball Ice Blue Mic and

a Lexmark 2404939 X2670 All-in-One Printer Copy/Print/Scan.

Any advice for any of these would be welcomed, priority going to the webcam preferably as I used that one the most, it has a mic, and it's the most important.

UPDATE:

I tried this:

ferociousmadman@ferociousmadman-CM5675:~$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype &

but got this:

[1] 2962
ferociousmadman@ferociousmadman-CM5675:~$ ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

The cam worked for a video call while I had the konsole open, but then stopped when I closed it. **It is no longer working now.** It's just gray or trippy rainbow colors appear.  My snowball mic works though. I just had to change the order of what the primary mic was in my sound settings. I still need help with my printer/scanner machine as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Microsoft VX1000 webcam](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26533/installing-microsoft-vx1000-webcam)

Comment: Actually none of that applies because my cam is already installed and working with cheese (as I've laid out in my post), it's just not properly working with skype for some reason. It also doesn't say anything about the Snowball Blue Mic or the Lexmark printer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87660/no-picture-with-a-microsoft-vx-1000-webcam-in-skype this might help with the web cam for starters

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244295/does-blue-microphones-snowball-ice-work-with-ubuntu-12-04 and for the mic...

Comment: I posted an update to my issues. Your link for the webcam seemed to help, but only if I use the command line. If this is regularly required that's fine, but I was curious if there was a way to resolve the issue permanently? Also, the video quality is somewhat poor, although that's of minor importance. the mic I was able to fix just by going into my sound settings and changing it to the primary mic.

Comment: is your system 64 or 32 bit

Comment: 64 bit Kubuntu 14.04